# UNIX stat time format

Tags: bash, time, formatting

Is it possible to format the time output of stat? I am using

```
stat -c '%n %A %z' $filename
```

in a bash script, but its time format is not what I want. Is it possible to change this format in the command, or would I have to manually do it later?

An example output follows:

```
/lib drwxr-xr-x 2010-11-15 04:02:38.000000000 -0800
```

Comment: your question is ambiguous, please update your question with your expected output

Comment: the output is irrelevant; i just wanted to know if formatting was possible inside of stat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 + $(stat -c '%Z' $filename ) secs"
```

Which gives you only the date.  You can format the date using date's formatting options (see [man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date)), for example:

```
date -d "1970-01-01 + $(stat -c '%Z' $filename ) secs" '+%F %X'
```

This doesn't give you the name and permissions but you may be able to do that like:

```
echo "$(stat -c '%n %A' $filename) $(date -d "1970-01-01 + $(stat -c '%Z' $filename ) secs"  '+%F %X')"
```

Comment: This shows the time in UTC. To show local time: `/bin/date -d "$(stat -c '%z' $filename)" "+%F %X"`

Answer (score 9):

You can simply strip of the decimal portion like this:

```
stat -c '%n %A %z' "$filename" | sed 's/\(:[0-9]\{2\}\)\.[0-9]* /\1 /'
```

**Edit:**

Here's another way to truncate the decimal portion:

```
stat -c '%n %A %.19z' "$filename"
```

This depends on the date being 19 characters long: `2010-11-15 04:02:38`