# Mass rename files (bash)

Tags: bash, rename

I have several folders with photos and each an average of 15 thousand photos and now I want one go for a script to rename files.
May the name of the file
obraz2.jpg.1 to obraz2.jpg.1500 and now chcaiłbym to each file name was changed to the date when it was created, eg: 010912-04-00-34.jpg file from 1 September 2012 hour 4 minutes 0 seconds and 34, have a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copy jpg files in a directory to a new name based solely on creation date
# FROM: obraz2.jpg.1 > 1500  Created on: 2012-04-18 18:51:44
# TO:    20120418_185144.jpg
for i in *.*
do
#  mod_date=$(stat -c "%y" "$i"|sed 's/\..*$//')
#  mod_date=$(stat -c "%y" "$i"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|sed 's/\..*$//')
mod_date=$(stat --format %y "$i"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}'|cut -f1 -d'.'|sed 's/[: -]//g')
 cp "$i" "$mod_date".jpg
done
```

I just have a problem that was the name he gave
010912-04-00-34.jpg and this is not a script that does 20120418_185144.jpg what should be changed to make it just like I want, I'll add the script, I found myself not written.

Comment: So you want to mass rename the files already renamed with the date format that you want? Im not sure I understand your problem. What is chcailbym??? Please rephrase your question details, it is hard to understand.

Comment: What is "chciałbym"    google tranlator "I"  sorry my language is polish

Comment: If your problem is with date formatting, take a look at this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181552/unix-stat-time-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181552/unix-stat-time-format)

Comment: All programmers understand sample input data, and sample required output, please edit your question to include both, especially the problem cases of inputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reformat your date string you can use the `date` program as follows:

```
for i in *.*; do
     stat_date=$(stat --format %y "$i"|awk '{print $1"_"$2}' | cut -f1 -d'.'|sed 's/_/ /g')
     date_fmt=$(date --date="$stat_date" +"%d%m%y-%H-%M-%S")
     cp $i ${date_fmt}.jpg
done
```